# Is subtraction defined in any metric space?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose I have two functions $f, g: X \to Y $ which are continuous and $(X, d_{X})$, $(Y, d_{Y})$ are two metric spaces. Can I define a function $h = f - g$, or does this not make sense.

That is, does $h(x) = f(x) -g(x)$  not make sense in $Y$, since subtraction is not necessarily defined there? Hopefully, this is not a bad question.

Comment: What properties do you want from your "subtraction"? Unless you specify these, the formula $f-g$ is just a notation without meaning

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see. Well I am trying to show that, given some assumption, $h(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in X$. I suppose in this case, if I define $h = d_{Y}(f(x), g(x))$, then, by definition of a distance, $f(x) = g(x)$ only when $d_{Y}(f(x), g(x)) = 0$, so maybe I could just use this as $h$ instead?

Comment: Yes, that's a very good idea.